# Setting Tiered Storage on Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to implement Tiered Storage on Apache Kafka such that I keep overall 14 days of data; I would like to have 2 days of data stored on the local Apache cluster drives, and the records of the oldest 12 days to be kept on a remote S3 storage.
Several resources indicate that this capability was going to be released on Apache Kafka version 3.0 (which is already released).

- https://kreuzwerker.de/en/post/apache-kafka-tiered-storage-and-why-you-should-care
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lgGgHpYcRs

Looking at the official Apache Kafka documentation, I only see these configurations related to remote storage:

```
local.retention.bytes
local.retention.ms
retention.ms
retention.bytes
remote.storage.enable
```

But there is no mention how to set it up for specified storage technologies such as HDFS or S3.

The Confluent documentation, on the other hand, is more detailed. But all the setting start with confluent i.e.

```
confluent.tier.feature=true
confluent.tier.enable=true
confluent.tier.backend=S3
confluent.tier.s3.bucket=<BUCKET_NAME>
confluent.tier.s3.region=<REGION>
```

My question is how to setup Tiered Storage for S3 on **Apache Kafka**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not fully implemented yet. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7739.

Comment: Yes, simply not ready yet. Target release was pushed to 3.2. It was originally planned to be released on 3.0.

Comment: Has tiered storage become available now?

Answer (score 3):

As per [**KIP-405**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-405%3A+Kafka+Tiered+Storage), this feature is still in progress upstream. From what I recall about it, there was never going to be implementations of the storage interfaces offered out of the box with Kafka project, anyway. For example, Uber might open-source their own HDFS/S3 Kafka storage plugins.

Confluent has gone ahead and merged the pull-request(s) for the feature and written their own S3 tier plugin for their Enterprise solution (referred to as Confluent Server).

Comment: Thanks OneCricketeer, so what exactly is going to be included in the Apache package? Several talks on Kafka Summit mentioned tiered storage on S3/HDFS will be available on Apache Kafka 3.0 release, seems like that target was missed... I'm still not sure what exactly is going to be available with the Apache release? some generic interface which we'll need to build target specific plugins for?

Comment: It wasn't missed. It's right here https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/storage/api/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/server/log/remote/storage/RemoteStorageManager.java

Comment: Has tiered storage become available now? @OneCricketeer?